# Assignment initialization of a constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I am trying out different versions of calling the constructor, and I came up with this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class game{

    public:
        float version;
        string name;
        game()
        {
            name = "game";
            version = 1.0;
        }
        game(float v,string n)
        {
            version = v;
            name = n;
        }
        game(float v)
        {
            version = v;
            name="any";
        }
};
int main()
{
    game lol1(1.0,"league of legends"); //functional form
    game lol2 = 2.0;    //assignment form
    game lol3{3.0,"league2"}; //uniform initialization
    game *pt = &lol1;
    cout<<pt->name<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Every statement compiles, but if I write

```
 game lol2 = 2.0,"league of legends2"; //code 2
```

I get an error:

> expected unqualified-id before string constant

But the following code works fine:

```
game lol2 = {2.0,"league of legends2"}; //code 3
```

I am not getting what exactly the issue is with the second code. Any ideas?

Comment: You can condense your constructors down to a single one using default parameters.

Comment: And for amusement, add a constructor that only takes a string ....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you call "assignment form" is a **copy initialization**.

It works as if a temporary object is constructed from *a single argument* specified as initializer, and is then passed to the class' copy constructor or move constructor.

So, the code

```
game lol2 = 2.0,"league of legends2"; //code 2
```

… is just syntactically invalid.

---

Tip: Instead of three constructors, where the second adds a first argument, and the third adds a second argument, you can just use default argument values:

```
class game{

public:
    float version;
    string name;
    game(float v = 1.0,string n = "game")
        : version( v ), name( n )
    {}
};
```

The `:` syntax is a constructor member initializer list.

It can sometimes be more efficient, sometimes necessary, and anyway is usually more concise and conventional.

Comment: Just for completeness: It should be `game(float v = 1.0,string n = "game")`, not `game(float v = 1.0,string n = "game)`, because the code won't compile with the missing quote.

Comment: @Striezel: Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf ,Just little doubt, as u told "It works as if a temporary object is constructed from a single argument specified as initializer, so according the promblem ,A new object is created with version = 2.0 with code 2?

Comment: @SubSea: The temporary is in practice always optimized away. That's called "elision" of the temporary and the copy or move constructor call. But still, since the construction of a temporary plus implicit call of copy or move constructor call is the spec, a copy or move constructor must be accessible and must not be declared `explicit`.

Answer (score 4):

You are not using the correct grammar to initialize a object from multiple values.  When you do

```
game lol2 = 2.0,"league of legends2";
```

The grammer expects a variable name after the comma like

```
type name1 = value1, name2 = value2;
```

So you get an error as you have

```
type name1 = value1, value2;
                    ^ missing variable declaration here
```

When you have multiple variables that you need to construct with you can only use the folowing forms

```
type name = {value1, value2, ..., valuen};
type name{value1, value2, ..., valuen};
auto name = type{value1, value2, ..., valuen};
type name(value1, value2, ..., valuen);
auto name = type(value1, value2, ..., valuen);
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the comma operator in this context? Do you get a complaint about the type of argument? Test this by adding a parenthesis around (then you do get comma operator for sure).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Oops.  It is just bad grammar.  fixing

Comment: @NathanOliver ,there is no error like missing variable declartion here ,but i got your point of constructin objects with multiple variables.

Comment: @SubSea Yeah that is not what you will actually get.  I was just putting it in human readable language.

Comment: @NathanOliver .okay.i got you..:)